# creating tree using the own database in jstree

Tags: php, jstree

Being a beginner in `JStree` ,i would like to know how to implement a database tree from my own database..i have tried the code from the  [Jstree](http://www.jstree.com/demo/) but i am not able to continue and get what i expected..so please help me to perform and proceed further by suggesting the modifications at the required places.